# How to make content take up the aside area as well using grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The grid-template-areas is being used here. However, the main area is not taking up the rest of the area, and I dont need aside for my project.

How can I make the main area take up the rest of the area?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav content side" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid #61dafb;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "nav" "content" "side" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto/* Header */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Nav */
    1fr/* Content */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Sidebar */
    auto;
    /* Footer */
  }
  nav,
  aside {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div>Header</div>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <div>nav</div>
  </nav>

  <main>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <div>Footer</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Attaching JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fgmwe281/2/

I am trying to use grid-template-areas for my boilerplate code for layout. However, unable to get the main content to take up the space on right(the area for aside).

[image: screenshot-of-layout]

Comment: Change `"nav content side"` to `"nav content content"`

Comment: I would solve it by simply not using `template-areas` at all. It will shorten the code and still work dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip `grid-template-areas` completely. It is nice for beginners as it visually displays the areas but overall it increases the size of necessary code. On top of that, it is easier to just skip it and letting the header and the footer span the entire with by using `grid-column: 1 / -1;`.

If you change the `grid-template-columns` to `min-content auto min-content` then the sidebar and the navigation will only consume as much space as needed. In this case, I sued the width on the containing div. If it exist then it will consume 200px width, if it doesn't, then it will consume no space:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto min-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

nav > div,
aside > div {
  width: 200px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto auto;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 769px) {
    .container {
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    }
}

header {
  border: 1px solid #61dafb;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div>Header</div>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <div>nav</div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <div>main</div>
  </main>
  
  <aside></aside>
  
  <footer>
    <div>Footer</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```